# Radius of convergence continuous in coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, real-numbers

Let $a_k(y)$ be a collection of functions. Suppose that $f_y(x) = \sum_{0}^\infty a_k(y) x^k$  has radius of convergence $R(y)>0$ for some fixed $y$. Are there conditions on the $a_k$ which ensure that $R$ is continuous in some neighborhood of $y$?